# How to use constant in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot retrieve `string` from `myConstant` in a service.
What am I doing wrong here and how to fix it? Please provide me sample of code.

```
   // Define Angular App
    var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar']).constant('myConstant', {
        string: 'myString',
        size: 30
    });


    'use strict';
    app.factory('devicesService', ['$http', 'myConstant', function ($http) {
        var serviceBase = myConstant.string; // PROBLEM HERE
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is example for using constant in angular: add it to app.js

```
.constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
    AuthenticatedSuccess: 'auth-user-success',
})
```

in you controller:

```
.controller('ApplicationController', function ($scope, AUTH_EVENTS) {
        console.log(AUTH_EVENTS.AuthenticatedSuccess);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add constants to your application using either [`constant`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) or [`value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value).

Both are exactly the same with just a slight difference. That is values inside [`constant`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) can never be changed, while values inside [`value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value) can be changed using [`decorator`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator).

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.constant('MY_CONSTANT', {
    value1: 'value 123',
});

app.variable('MY_VARIABLE', {
    value1: 'value 456',
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, MY_CONSTANT, MY_VARIABLE) {
    console.log('constant: ', MY_CONSTANT.value1);
    console.log('variable: ', MY_VARIABLE.value1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine if you do add the constant as a parameter in yout factory function:

```
app.factory('devicesService', ['$http', 'myConstant', function ($http, myConstant) {
```

In your example, you only added it to the *min-safe array*, but not in the actual function.
I'm guessing that that's why you had a problem there, because the function wasn't aware of any `myConstant` variable.